# ArgumentError: After create callback :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions has not been defined. devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for authenticating a rails-api application. I have included these devise modules in my user model as shown below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :confirmable
end
```

The problem is when i do a `POST` request on the email registration endpoint, `http://localhost:3000/auth` with `email`, `password` and `password_confirmation` as params. It only succeeds once after a server restart. All subsequent requests to register an user fail with this error:

```
{
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "#<ArgumentError: After create callback     :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions has not been defined>",
  "traces": {
         ...
   }
```

This means I have to restart the server every time I want to register a user.

This is what I have in the `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'devise', github: "plataformatec/devise"
gem 'devise_token_auth', github: "lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth"
```

**EDIT**

When I make any change in `ApplicationController` and save it. The request succeeds without restarting the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution, the problem was this line in the `create` method of the `RegistrationsController` in the `devise_token_auth`:

```
# override email confirmation, must be sent manually from ctrl
    resource_class.skip_callback("create", :after, :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions)
```

I don't know why i would want to skip sending confirmation instructions, while the behaviour i want is to send the confirmation automatically when a user is created.

So I created an override of `RegistrationController`'s `create` method using information on controllers ovverride provided in `devise_token_auth` gem docs. In the override, I commented out the line and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**After Adding this line:**
 resource_class.skip_callback("create", :after, :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions)

Just perform the task

**And add this line for setting the callback again.**
 resource_class.set_callback("create", :after, :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions)

we need to set callback again after skipping it.